# Full width web pages and screen readers

Tags: html, accessibility, screen-readers

I work in an office that receives government funding so our website needs to be highly accessible. We are brainstorming ideas for a major site redesign. We kind of like a full width idea, but one employee says that they cause issues with screen readers. Does anyone have any experience of this? If there are any websites out there that can verify this information can you please share the links?

Thanks

Comment: I don't see how it can cause a problem with screen readers - most screen readers will read your web page with as if the css has been turned off so as long as your page flows correctly and has all the correct headings and internal links it should be fine.  you can test your pages with this: http://www.browsealoud.co.uk/page.asp?pg_id=80004

Comment: Not exactly clear what you mean by "full width". Can you elaborate? There are some CSS properties that affect screen readers (`display: none` will not be read for instance), but the width of elements shouldn't affect anything.

Comment: While I'm not aware of any screen reader issues with full width layouts, there may be other accessibility issues with them. Reading long lines of text off a screen can be difficult for users for a number of reasons, and you may wish to take that into account by limiting the length of text lines. That doesn't necessarily mean not using the full width though. For example, one approach may be to layout your content in multiple columns.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As said in the comments, full-width or fixed-width has virtually zero impact on a screen-reader. The only thing a full-width page does is make the content longer visually (since it has more room to expand horizontally). From a screen reader perspective, widths don't really matter. It's just reading the text as if it were on one long line (obviously breaking it up in paragraphs and headings and such changes the way it's read).

That being said, going full-width can actually hurt accessibility b/c [long horizontal lines of text are difficult to read](http://baymard.com/blog/line-length-readability). Accessibility is complex and there are a lot of different facets to it to consider.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I'm actually using Bootstrap for this site and its grid system so I'm not too worried about texting being extremely long